# Function is not defined though js file reference is in header

Tags: javascript

I am working on a page on a website (see http://www.quick-conversions.com/currency).

I am attaching a `onkeyup="doConversion('...')` on each input field. The corresponding function is defined in a javascript file available at: http://www.quick-conversions.com/sites/MyScripts/PHP/currency.js

In the source page, this file seems to be imported properly in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.quick-conversions.com/sites/MyScripts/PHP/currency.js?m4xpzi"></script>
```

But the function is not fired and Firebug says that it is not defined? I am running out of ideas to solve this issue. Anyone has an idea of what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: if you look the console there is a *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (*

Comment: I guess I learned something about Firebug here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's error on your source files.

missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]

var updateConversion(src_rate, value) {

curren...?m4xpzi (line 104, col 20)

Answer (score 2):

Loading the page I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( 
        currency.js line 104
```

That is likely the cause.

You have:

```
var updateConversion(src_rate, value) {
```

Which should be either:

```
function updateConversion(src_rate, value) {
```

or

```
var updateConversion = function (src_rate, value) {
```